# Apostrophes show up as '&#39;' in chat room timeout reason

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, room-owner, chat-timeout

I was playing with the new room owner power on chat, timeouts, and passed `I'm testing this` as timeout reason. However, this showed up as:

> [*This room was placed in timeout for 30 seconds; I&#39;m testing this.*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31304010#31304010)

So I thought I&#39;d report this bug. Could this please be fixed?

Comment: For a temporary workaround - don&#39;t timeout rooms.

Comment: On which site you're a mod?..

Comment: @nicael Room timeouts are now a room owner feature! Cool, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, didn't know.

Comment: That&#8217;s not an apostrophe.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It is. https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref - &#8217; is called a "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK", but &#39; is called "APOSTROPHE" :)

Comment: @ProgramFOX: I cannot see anything along the lines of that on that site. Anyway, it is the closest approximation to the apostrophe in ASCII, where they did not have the luxury of separately encoding ‘ (opening single quote), ’ (closing single quote and apostrophe), and some others. Unicode recommends to use &#8217; for the apostrophe.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft The 9th element, &apos; aka &#39; has as tooltip "APOSTROPHE". Lower on the page there is &#8217; with "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK" as tooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And there I was, thinking double-encoding was liked by everyone.

Fixed and deployed.